# Cancel task after a period of time

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I have this code that do this tasks:

```
        objErrorLogging.LogActivity("Starting processing jobs")

        Dim jobListSetup As New List(Of Task(Of processingJob)) From {setupGPJob(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("GPService"))}

        If doForecast Then jobListSetup.Add(setupGPJob(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CastService")))

        Dim jobList() As ProcessingJob = Await Task(Of ProcessingJob).WhenAll(Of ProcessingJob)(jobListSetup)

        'Run through the list and set them up to await for them to run to completetion
        Dim jobResultsList As New List(Of Task(Of ProcessingResult))(jobList.Count)
        For Each listedJob As ProcessingJob In jobList                
            jobResultsList.Add(listedJob.GetResultAsync)
        Next

        
        Await Task.WhenAll(jobResultsList)
```

Now my problem is I have to set a timeout that if task is taking time for a period of 25 minutes, it will cancel the tasks and just log the errors. I know how to log errors but I don't know to set the time, where and how to put it there. I've read about Cancellation Token Source but I don't how to apply it there. This is the only thing that I've understand:

```
        Dim cts As New CancellationTokenSource()
        cts.CancelAfter(1500000) '25 minutes
```

so maybe someone could show me how to apply this on my code, where do I put the cts.token? Thank you!

---

This is setupGPJob code:
Notes: ProcessingTask definition is internal which I don't have access, I can only use it.

```
   Private Async Function setupGPJob(ByVal url As String) As Task(Of ProcessingJob)
    Try
        objErrorLogging.LogActivity(String.Format("Starting processing task {0}", url))
        Dim processURI As New Uri(url)

        Dim streetCred As TokenCredential = Await AuthenticationManager.Current.GenerateCredentialAsync(processURI, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("UserName"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Password"))
        SyncLock _syncObject
            'Adds the necessary Credentials object to the list of allowed objects so that the service can be accessed.
            AuthenticationManager.Current.AddCredential(streetCred)
        End SyncLock

        Dim task As ProcessingTask = Await ProcessingTask.CreateAsync(processURI)

        Dim newJob As ProcessingJob = task.CreateJob(Await task.CreateDefaultParametersAsync)
        newJob.Start()

        Return newJob

    Catch ex As Exception
        objErrorLogging.LogError(_CLASS_NAME, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.StackTrace, ex)
        objErrorLogging.LogActivity(" AN ERROR OCCURRED.       ")
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: When you initialize a CTS with a timeout (a TimeSpan, usually), the timer it sets up notifies that the time has expired and all registrations are canceled. Same as calling `[CTS].Cancel()`. The CancellationToken you get from the CTS (`[CancellationTokeSource].Token`) can throw or you can check whether a cancellation has been requested (`[CancellationToken].IsCancellationRequested`). You need to pass that CancellationToken to your tasks and to all other async methods used in your tasks that accept a CancellationToken (hopefully, all of them)

Comment: How do I use the cancellation token then in my code? If this code: is the one doing the task [ Await Task.WhenAll(jobResultsList)]? Sorry, I get the logic but still I don't know how to properly use it.

Comment: You `setupGPJob()` method requires an overloaded Constructor that accepts a CancellationToken. `Task.WhenAll()` just completes when the collections of Tasks it receives all have completed (in a way or another)

Comment: I've updated my code, I put the content of setupGPJob, I know I should pass as parameter the cancellation token, but inside the code where should I put it?

Comment: Hi, is it possible to cancel the tasks here?